# Nginx multiple server with different port

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm trying to serve : one django back-end , 2 reactjs front-end .
the back-end work well but for the front-ends only one of theme work .

this is my nginx and front-end Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 as build1

WORKDIR /frontend
COPY ./frontend/package.json ./
COPY ./frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend/ ./
RUN npm run build


FROM node:lts-alpine3.12 as build2

WORKDIR /frontend2
COPY ./frontend2/package.json ./
COPY ./frontend2/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend2/ ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine
COPY  ./webserver/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build1 /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1
COPY --from=build2 /frontend2/build /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2
```

this is my default.conf:

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "localhost";

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1;

    location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }  

}

server {
    listen 8080 ;
    server_name "localhost";

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2;

    location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
        
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }  

}
```

and this is the results for port 80 :
[image]

and this is the result for port 8080:
[image]

Update :
this is my docker-compose :

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:

  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/backend/staticfiles

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./webserver/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
volumes:
  staticfiles:
```

Comment: Based on the configuration you provided, it looks like you are trying to serve two separate React front-ends on different ports (80 and 8080) using a single nginx server.

The first front-end is being served on port 80 and is working as expected. However, the second front-end on port 8080 is not working. This could be due to several reasons.

Comment: One possible issue could be that the React front-end on port 8080 is not being built correctly. This could be due to errors in the source code or in the build process. You can try building the front-end on port 8080 separately and see if there are any issues.

Another possibility is that there could be issues with the nginx configuration for the second front-end on port 8080. You can try checking the nginx logs to see if there are any errors being thrown that could be causing the issue.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the contents of the package.json and package-lock.json files for the second front-end, as well as any error messages you are seeing in the browser or in the console.

Comment: Without more information, it's difficult to say for sure what is causing the issue with the second front-end on port 8080. However, the above suggestions should help you troubleshoot and identify the problem.

Comment: my main goal is serve 2 reactjs applications , the port numbers dosen't matter for me

Comment: Please add  "8080:8080" to your docker-compose in Nginx.ports
,After this line:

      - "80:80"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different server names for frontend other localhost,

Use this default.conf

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.loc;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  newapp.loc;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 newapp.loc
127.0.0.1 myapp.loc
```

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide your docker-compose file

Comment: i did now you can check now

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/uzrnem/ meet me on linkedin, will solve it

Comment: Yes, use custome host name, make that entry in /etc/hosts file and for frontend2

Comment: i tried it now and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your docker-compose, you didn't connect your container port 8080 to your local port 8080.
So when you open localhost:8080 in your browser, you get connection error, because this port isn't open now.

please use this docker-compose, and let me know if you have any problem with it:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:

  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/backend/staticfiles

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./webserver/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - backend
volumes:
  staticfiles:
```